# How to get news from another website via RSS

Tags: wordpress, rss

I have a blog and I want some automatically - generated news on it. I have found a few news websites which generate RSS feeds and I want to auto-post them to my blog. 
I have done this using the WP-o-Matic plugin, but since the RSS feed's content is limited to some point, the entire news' text does not show up on my blog.

Is there a way to get the whole content of the post the RSS feed is linking to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people that need a solution to the problem I described .. 
There are services like:

http://fulltextrssfeed.com/

http://fullrss.net/

http://www.wizardrss.com/

You can use them to do the job for you. They fetch the RSS feed, crawl the websites and extract the full articles for you. After that, they  provide a RSS feed of their own with the extracted data.
You can combine the extracted data (the RSS feed the service provides you with) with a wordpress plugin like WP-o-Matic. That way the plugin connects to the RSS feed of the service and the service extracts the content from the original RSS feed.

Have in mind that those services are not perfect. Due to complex  website layouts, these services might be unable to find the content, or include things that are not a part of the articles. A manual check of the output is advised.

Comment: FYI, I also checked out these services and there are many reasons why I wouldn't use them in a production app. The biggest issue is that like my answer states above: they are just providing screen-scraped data for you, markup tags and all (which is bad for formatting later). Try it out: go to an arstechnica.com article, then open the same article in the "full RSS" feed. If you do a diff of the content, you'll see it's just html from the page. The other big issue is that you have no SLA for their feeds, so they could go down any time without notice.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to code this yourself. Let's say you subscribe to an RSS feed for Google News. You can parse their feed to get the original URL of the summarized article, but then you're going to have to make a request to that URL and fetch the content on that page. Unless the source happens to make whole articles available via its own RSS feed (unlikely), you're probably in markup-scraping territory.

Have to say this: consider the ethical/legal implications of duplicating entire original content on your site (as opposed to summary snippets), even with proper attribution.

Answer (score 0):

To the services alrady listed at the top, you can also check **[http://www.FeedsAPI.org](http://www.feedsapi.org)** , FeedsAPI brings to the table that it takes the process of posting the articles directly to your secret blog email for you, so all you need to do is manage the publication in the wordpress admin, and you can also get it targeting a specific feed to receive the results you want. Anothe alternative will be the  combinations of one of those services with **IFTTT** . I hope this could help.